# Starting an acitvity form where the user left

Tags: java, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-activityrecord

Is it possible to start an activity from where the user left before closing the app in android using shared preferences or any other technique?

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried but there is a chance of doing that but the first activity should be splashActivity....Check the shared preference value of the activity and then send to the corresponding activity....

```
public void checkActivityCount() {
        AppPreference mAppreference = new AppPreference(SplashActivity.this);

        int activityCount = mAppPreference.getActivityCount();

        switch(activityCount) {

        case 1 :
            Intent iNext = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(iNext);
            break;

        case 2 :
            Intent iNext = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(iNext);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Create a unique int value for diff activity and store them in the shared preference.....

Hope this will help you Happeeee...programming.....